# IntelliJ IDEA Using External Tools/Macros to Execute "ionic run" Using a Keymap

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-idea-2016

I'm getting tired of opening and closing the terminal to run small things like `ionic run` that need to be executed fairly frequently early on in development.

I initially tried a macro, but they don't register double clicking ALT, and opening a new terminal, and eventually closing the terminal.  It only registers typing `cd mobile`, and `ionic run`.  So I found a post on External Tools, but I don't understand how to setup or use them even using the docs.  Is there a way to simply:

1. Open a terminal
2. Type: cd mobile
3. Type: ionic run
4. Close the terminal

that I can keymap?

Or types into the terminal/executes a script file I can drop into a folder and keymap so the terminal doesn't have to open and close.

Comment: Not sure if this would be acceptable to you, but you could make a new run/debug configuration and choose 'Bash'. Then just point to a bash script that does whatever you need. Then you could use ctrl+option+D to launch it on OSX. Not sure what the shortcut is on windows.

Comment: Only issue is unlike a solution that might include external tools/macros you can't add macros so it automatically adds the `$ProjectFileDir$` then since all our projects are setup the same way I can just `cd /mobile` and execute `ionic run` and use it in all our projects.  That said it's a good short term solution.  Thanks

Comment: I see. I've never used the external tools but I guess you could use some environment variables to point to the project root. Good luck anyways.